# Finding the dominant wavelength and excitation purity from ChromaticityPlot

Tags: color

I have a set of colors which I plot with `ChromaticityPlot`:

```
colors = {XYZColor[{0.6608454000597024, 0.3391286637993033, 
    0.00002593614099418745}], 
   XYZColor[{0.24521083303940436`, 0.6358783548087138, 
    0.11891081215188183`}], 
   XYZColor[{0.3673789216544311, 0.5433966109723922, 
    0.08922446737317652}], 
   XYZColor[{0.5568915376864929, 0.40471010391142537`, 
    0.03839835840208168}]};
ChromaticityPlot[colors, Frame -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive["TR", Black, 16], 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[10]}, FrameLabel -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 250, 
 Appearance -> {"FilledVisibleSpectrum", "Wavelengths" -> True}]
```

[image]

How can I calculate the dominant wavelength and excitation purity for each point as defined in [A. K. R. Choudhury, *Principles of Colour and Appearance Measurement* (2014)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/chromaticity-diagram)? Namely:

> [...] a line is drawn from the neutral point $\rm N$ (location of the illuminant in the case of coloured light, and of the perfect diffuser in the case of surface colour) $\rm O$ and $\rm O'$ in the chromaticity diagram [...] The wavelength of the monochromatic light at the point of intersection (point $\rm D$) [...] is termed the **dominant wavelength**, $\lambda_d$, for the respective test colour.
>
> The ratio of the lines $\rm NO$ and $\rm ND$ provides a measure called **excitation purity**, similar to saturation [...]: $$pe=\rm\frac{|NO|}{|ND|}.$$
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall algorithm is very simple:

1. Find the boundary curve of pure wavelengths.
2. Determine the position of white point $\rm N$ in $xy$ space.
3. Determine the position of your color $\rm O$ in $xy$ space.
4. Construct a half line between $\rm N$ and $\rm O$ and find its intersection with the boundary curve in the correct direction.
5. Extract the corresponding $\lambda_{\rm dominant}$ and calculate $p_e$.

However, functions for working with color spaces in Mathematica are, as far as I know, not very much exposed, so I am providing an answer which uses several internal (undocumented) functions. An obvious warning is that one should use these functions with caution, as they may change in the future versions of Mathematica.

A short description of used functions and symbols:

```
(* List of 71 wavelengths and the corresponding {x, y} values in CIE31 *)
Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths
Image`ColorOperationsDump`$coord["CIE31"]

(* xy of D50 white point in CIE31 *)
Image`ColorOperationsDump`findWhite["D50", "CIE31"]

(* Color conversion to xy space in CIE31 *)
Image`ColorOperationsDump`CConvert[color, "CIE31"]
```

Also, there are several ways of determining an intersection between a line and a curve. Herein, I use `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``.

Now to the actual code:

```
(* Preload symbols in Image`ColorOperationsDump` *)
ChromaticityPlot[White];

(* Minimal and maximal values of λ in visible spectrum *)
{minλ, maxλ} = Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths[[{1, -1}]];

(* Interpolation of function λ |-> {x, y} *)
λxy = Interpolation[Transpose[{Image`ColorOperationsDump`$wavelengths, 
       Image`ColorOperationsDump`$coord["CIE31"]}]];
λxyErr[λ_?NumericQ, point_] := Norm[λxy[λ] - point]^2;

(* White point in xy space *)
pointN = Rest@Image`ColorOperationsDump`findWhite["D50", "CIE31"];

plotNOLine[pointO_, reverse_ : False] := 
  Show[ParametricPlot[λxy[t], {t, 400, 700}, 
    PlotHighlighting -> None, Mesh -> 50, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    MaxRecursion -> 15], 
   Graphics@HalfLine[If[reverse, Reverse, Identity]@{pointN, pointO}]];

findDominantWavelengthAndExcitationPurity[color_?ColorQ, showPlot_ : False] := 
 Module[{pointO, pointDs, pointD, plots, plot, ind, dominantλ, pe},
  pointO = Rest@Image`ColorOperationsDump`CConvert[color, "CIE31"];
  
  (* Plot NO line in both direction and find intersections with boundary *)
  plots = {plotNOLine[pointO], plotNOLine[pointO, True]};
  pointDs = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections /@ plots;
  
  (* Find which direction produces an intersection, take N-O-D as default *)
  ind = First@First@Position[pointDs, l_ /; Length[l] > 0, 1];
  plot = plots[[ind]];
  pointD = First@pointDs[[ind]];
  
  (* Find corresponding dominant λ *)
  dominantλ = λ /. Last@NMinimize[{λxyErr[λ, pointD], minλ <= λ <= maxλ}, λ];
  pe = Norm[pointN - pointO]/Norm[pointN - pointD];
  
  If[showPlot,
   Show[ChromaticityPlot[color, 
     Appearance -> {"FilledVisibleSpectrum", "Wavelengths" -> True}], 
    plot, Graphics[{Point@pointN, PointSize[Large], Point@pointO, 
      Point@pointD}], 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(dominant\)]\) = ", 
       dominantλ, ",  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(e\)]\) = ", 
       pe}], ImageSize -> 300]
   , {dominantλ, pe}]
  ]
```

Let's try on some simple colors:

```
findDominantWavelengthAndExcitationPurity[#, True] & /@ {Orange, Cyan, Purple} // Row
```

[image]

And now on your colors:

```
findDominantWavelengthAndExcitationPurity /@ colors
(* {{608.418, 1.00083}, {534.919, 0.654892}, {560.479, 0.704107}, {592.227, 0.871955}} *)
```